# Oracle SQL, while creating a new table an error appear ORA-00942

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table, ora-00942

I got a problem with oracle SQL. I just have installed and used for short time. When Im trying to create new table I got error ORA-00942 "Table or view does not exist". Im newbie at this, I was trying to find similar problem topics but I found just one and without actual links (["Table or view does not exist" on create table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090020/table-or-view-does-not-exist-on-create-table)). At another topics I did not find anything useful in my case. I would be grateful for helping me with solution.

That commend I have tried, then the error occurred:

```
CREATE TABLE customer1 (
    customer_id NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    mobile_nr NUMBER(9) UNIQUE CHECK(LENGTH(mobile_nr)=9),
    age NUMBER(3) CHECK(age>=18),
    city_id NUMBER(4) REFERENCES cities(city_id)
);
```

Comment: Does table `cities` exist?

Comment: You are right, there is no such table `cities`, Im just learning from some SQL course and author show all but I dont know what I make wrong. I loaded data base as on tutorial so it should be working like on author video I think. Is it possible that I made some mistake on loading data base?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in the database a table named cities? I expect not. That table is referenced in the foreign key: city_id NUMBER(4) REFERENCES cities(city_id). Thus, you must first create the table cities having the column city_id and a primary key constraint on it, then CREATE TABLE customer1.
Generally, I prefer having scripts that create the tables with the create table SQL not including the constraints, and adding constraints after creating the tables with alter table add constraint SQL statements.